# nodemailer error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I googled this but could not find an answer for my problem. here is my code

```
var xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Gmail",
  auth: {
    xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
      user: "dude@gmail.com", 
      clientId: "-",
      clientSecret: "-",
      refreshToken: "-"
       })
  }
});

app.post('/send', function (req, res) {
  var mailOptions = {
      from: 'dude',
      to: 'derp@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Email Example',
      text: 'username: ' + req.body.firstname,
      attachments:[
        {
          filename: req.files.myfile.name,
          content: new Buffer(req.files.myfile.data,'utf-8')
        }
      ]
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Message sent!!');
      res.send('sent');
    }
  });
});
```

i used to have this problem back when i did not use oauth2, now that im using it i thought it would go away but it didnt. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ok so it was because of the Anti-Virus software. i swear things like this make me feel like quitting.

Comment: Same here. To be specific, in my case it was Avasts mail shield. Thanks for doing the right thing and posting the answer even though you solved it yourself!

Comment: Thanks. That's I love Linux. My colleague was working on window and that's how we come here.

Comment: I laughed so hard at this. You just saved me a great deal of pain. Been at it for close to six hours until I finally decided to mute the antivirus. Funny thing it was working before. Maybe the antivirus just got suspicious and disabled it. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: you just saved me days of headaches and crying 

Answer (score 13):

Same was with me. My antivirus is **AVG**. Instead of turning the antivirus off in AVG you can go to Settings>Components>Email Shield>Customize>SSL Scanning and **uncheck** "Scan SSL connections".

In **Avast** Go Settings/Protection/Core Shields/Configure shield settings/Mail Shield
and **uncheck** "Scan outbound emails (SMTP)"